# Example of a toy ODE control problem for chemistry/chemical engineering application?

Tags: control-theory, optimal-control, chemistry

I work in control theory. I have a student who is interested in chemistry and chemical engineering problems. I thought it would be somewhat easy to find such a problem, but apparently coming up with such problems from chemistry is a lot harder than from classical mechanics.

Could someone give me a reference or provide a simple example of such a control problem?

Thank you so very much.

Comment: One interesting fact about ODEs modelling chemical reactions is that, assuming mass action kinetics, the RHS of the ODEs is polynomial. Hence, finding the equilibria may require some algebraic geometry. I find [chemical oscillators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chemical_oscillator) utterly fascinating, though there's no control input per se. Perhaps one can introduce one.

Comment: Check out kinetic batch reactors. [GPOPS II](http://www.gpops2.com/Examples/KineticBatchReactor.html) has a nice example of one.

If you're really pressed to come up with a problem, you can take any Lagrangian-type problem, $L(x,\dot{x},t)$, and turn it into an optimal control-type problem with $u=\dot{x}$, to make $L(x, u, t)$. Not the best answer but it could help get the gears turning and lead into something better.

Comment: Thank you @MichaelSparapany this is exactly the sort of thing I was looking for!

Comment: https://web.archive.org/web/20080827235300/http://controls.engin.umich.edu/wiki#Chemical_Process_Controls